# Vim command to find all function names that contain a string in their bodies, in a PHP source file

Tags: php, regex, vim, macros

How could I generate in VIM a list of names of functions from a PHP source file that contain a specific string in their bodies ?

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [ctags](http://ctags.sourceforge.net/). Create a tag file for you source file(or your entire project) and use for example `:ts /hello` to find all functions(or classes) that have `hello` in their name.

Comment: So I corrected the title: the string is inside functions' bodies. I asked for vim but a solution with `sed` and some `bash` would be great, too. Perhaps `ctags` is overkill ?

Comment: Tags would certainly help here but would not create a list of functions for you. See also [`:he tags-and-searches`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tagsrch.html#tags-and-searches) for other neat navigational tips and tricks.

Answer (score 0):

How about a python program? Note that you should replace some of this with [PLY](http://www.dabeaz.com/ply/)....

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
'''
Project: Python parser to search php functions for regex
Author: Spencer Rathbun
Date: 1/17/2012

Summary: Search glob files (assumed to be php source) for input regex, and list function and line numbers where found.
'''
import re, argparse
from glob import glob
def main(regex, infiles):
    theRegex = re.compile(regex)
    currFunction = ''

    for globFile in infiles:
        for f in glob(globFile):
            with open(f,'rb') as currFile:
                for lineNum, line in enumerate(currFile.readlines()):
                    if line.split(' ')[0] == 'function':
                        currFunction = line.split(' ')[1].split('(')[0]
                    if theRegex.search(line) != None:
                        print("In function {0}\n\tLine {1}: {2}".format(currFunction, lineNum+1, line))


if __name__ == "__main__":

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Search php source code for regex', version='%(prog)s 1.0')
    parser.add_argument('regex', type=str, default='', help='Regular expression')
    parser.add_argument('infiles', nargs='+', type=str, help='list of input files')
    args = parser.parse_args()
    main(args.regex, args.infiles)
```

Add it to your `~/bin` and make it executable. Then in vim, you can call it with `:!phpSearch.py yourRegex yourGlobPat`.

Comment: `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'currFunction' referenced before assignment`, invoked `./phpSearch.py mysql x.php`

Comment: @Niloct Whoops! Forgot to give it a starting value. I've fixed it. Note that it isn't a true php parser, and *will* make mistakes on the function names. You won't be able to fix that with just regex, which is why I included the link to PLY.

Comment: I was thinking about a simple macro, using `v%` for each `function` returned by vim search, and then printing the function name if this selection contains the string. `%` operator would get me the entire function body for each one.